# me sale error al instalar composer require caffeinated/shinobi para trabajar con roles y permisos

Tags: laravel-5

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es el error que me sale al momento de realizar la instalación en laravel para el uso de roles y permisos

Comment: ¿Que versión de PHP tienes?

Comment: Esta pregunta ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad, deberías editarla para añadir más detalles: ¿qué comandos estás ejecutando para instalar? ¿qué versiones estás usando? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error concreto? ¿aparece algo en los logs? Y por favor, pon los mensajes en modo texto y no como imágenes, las imágenes no se indexan y son menos accesibles. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 1):

Me encontraba con el mismo problema, al parecer el paquete Shinobi no tiene soporte para la versión 5.7 de Laravel. Trabaja con la versión 5.6